# Por qué al manejar un ICON en JFRAME me salta el error NullPointerException?

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, nullpointerexception, icons

Intento dar un icon a ciertos labels de algún que otro jframe, aunque ya tenga señalada la ruta donde están las imágenes del icon tal y como veis:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además, cuando lo veo desde la parte de diseño de netbeans el icono sí que tiene la imagen, pero cuando lo ejecuto...

Me salta el error de que no es capaz de encontrar la imagen que le he agregado, tal y como veis aquí:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado probando a poner la ruta de diferentes formas, pero sigue sin encontrarlo, ¿alguien sabe cómo hacerlo?

Esta es la estructura de mi proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes es producto del modo en que funciona Maven y no de tu código, puesto que este es correcto. Maven usa el directorio `src/main/java` (mapeado a `Source Packages` en NetBeans) solo para el código fuente, por lo que cualquier archivo cuya extensión no sea `.java` será excluído al momento de la compilación y por lo tanto no se depositará en el directorio `target\classes` ni en el JAR que se genere.

Esto quiere decir que tu imagen está siendo excluída y por tanto no existe en el directorio desde el que se ejecuta la aplicación (`target/classes`).

Para solucionar este problema debes mover todos esos archivos que no son de código fuente (`.java`) a el directorio `src/main/resources`. Si quieres que estos archivos estén en el mismo paquete donde están ahora debes crear la estructura de directorios correspondiente a tus paquetes dentro de este directorio.

En tu caso quedaría así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**NOTA:** En la imagen no se muestran todas tus clases porque nos las crees todas ya que solo intento mostrar la estructura del proyecto.

Comment: EFECTIVAMENTE! Muchas gracias !

Comment: Me tenía loco este problema desde ayer!!! Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score -1):

Prueba a quitar la primera barra del string y pon doble barra luego, o sea que quede así

```
FTP_images//main.png
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, pero no funciono :(

Comment: ya veo, prueba a poner dos puntos antes, y doble antibarra. así: "..//FTP_images//main.png" porque claro, el main, que es el directorio desde donde se ejecuta, está dentro de la carpeta FTP_interface, y por eso los  dos puntos, para subir previamente ese nivel.

Comment: Tampoco, es curioso, porque cuando selecciono la imagen del icono desde netbeans (desde la ventana de propiedades). Si que la encuentra, pero es cuando ejecuto el codigo que ya no lo encuentra.

Comment: de hecho, el error es un null pointer, no un file not found. ¿De qué clase es la variable main?

Comment: Solo tengo una clase, que es la principal (main) y esa variable se encuentra en esa misma clase, cosa que por cierto deberia cambiar los nombres.

Comment: Entonces, el problema debe ser que aún no se ha hecho el setVisible(). No estoy seguro, pero yo de ti probaría a poner el setIcon después del initComponents() de la clase... no me atrevo asegurartelo pero creo que por ahí van los tiros.

Comment: Al final era lo del usuario de arriba, que como tenia las imágenes dentro del provecto y no en una carpeta resources, no encontraba los archivos, pero una vez que metí las imágenes en esa carpeta y señale esa ruta los encontro. De todas formas, gracias por la ayuda.